# Using Map Object to Render React Components in Order

Tags: reactjs, performance, rendering

I receive an array of product objects like such from my backend.

```
products = [
  {id: 1, price: 10, category: "food", name: "apples"},
  {id: 2, price: 5, category: "supplies", name: "spoons"},
  {id: 3, price: 15, category: "pets", name: "cat treats"},
  {id: 4, price: 9, category: "food", name: "oranges"},
  // ...
]
```

I am looking to render all my products as strips based on their category in a specific order of priority (similar to how Netflix aligns their shows). I don't want them displayed in random order, such as the category strip of food being at the top, the next category strip being pets, etc.

I currently decided to create a map object since it keeps order as followed:

```
let filteredProducts = new Map([
  ["food", []],
  ["pets", []],
  ["supplies", []],
  // ...
])  

for (let product of products) {
  let category = product["category"]
  filteredProducts.get(category).push(product)
}
```

The goal is to then iterate through the map object and return multiple React Component of category strips from top to bottom.

My question is, I can't help but feel that there are more efficient ways to render this as I don't see map objects being utilized commonly. Are there more efficient and frequently used ways to filter and render by priority or is this in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I do believe there is more easier way to do this using Array `sort` function.
Please consider the snippet below.

```js
const products = [
  {id: 1, price: 10, category: "food", name: "apples"},
  {id: 2, price: 5, category: "supplies", name: "spoons"},
  {id: 3, price: 15, category: "pets", name: "cat treats"},
  {id: 4, price: 9, category: "food", name: "oranges"},
  // ...
]

const priority = [
  'food',
  'supplies',
  'pets'
]

const orderedProducts = products.sort(
  (p1, p2) => priority.indexOf(p1.category) - priority.indexOf(p2.category)
);
```

Let me know if this looks much cleaner & easier approach.